# Помогите с JS, как сделать выполнение данного кода синхронным?

Tags: javascript, асинхронность

Проблема в том, что getRelAU внутри выполняется асинхронно, и у меня    return ret; выполняется до выполнения двух функций getRelAU. Я поизучал промисы, но видимо чего-то недопонял? Сейчас от promise.then переходит в конец, return ret;

```js
isLiader: function() {

  var owner = this.get("Owner");
  if (!owner) {
    return false;
  }

  var managersParent = [];
  var idUser = this.get("Id");
  var ret = false;
  var getRelAU = this.getRelAU;

  async function f(getRelAU) {
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      getRelAU(
        idUser,
        function(result) {
          let managers = result.Managers;
          managers.forEach(function(item, i, managers) {
            managersParent.push(item.parentAU.value);
          });
          resolve("result");

        }, true
      );
    });

    // promise.then навешивает обработчики на успешный результат или ошибку
    promise
      .then(
        result => {
          getRelAU(
            owner,
            function(result1) {
              let organizations = result1.Organizations;
              organizations.forEach(function(item, i, organizations) {
                if (managersParent.includes(item.id)) {
                  ret = false;
                  return true;
                }

              });
              return false;
            }, true
          );
          return ret;
        },
        error => {
          // вторая функция - запустится при вызове reject
          alert("Rejected: " + error); // error - аргумент reject
        }
      );
  }

  f(getRelAU);
  return ret;
},
```

V2

```js
isLiader: function () {

                var owner = this.get("Owner");
                if (!owner) {
                    return false;
                }

                var managersParent = [];
                var idUser = this.get("Id");
                var ret = false;
                var getRelAU = this.getRelAU;

                async function f(getRelAU) {

                    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

                        getRelAU(
                            idUser,
                            function (result) {
                                let managers = result.Managers;
                                managers.forEach(function (item, i, managers) {
                                    managersParent.push(item.parentAU.value);
                                });
                                resolve("result");

                            }, true
                        );
                    });

                    // promise.then навешивает обработчики на успешный результат или ошибку
                    return promise
                        .then(
                            result => {
                                getRelAU(
                                    owner,
                                    function (result1) {
                                        let organizations = result1.Organizations;
                                        organizations.forEach(function (item, i, organizations) {
                                            if (managersParent.includes(item.id)) {
                                                ret = false;
                                                return true;
                                            }

                                        });
                                        return false;
                                    }, true
                                );
                                return ret;
                            },
                            error => {
                                // вторая функция - запустится при вызове reject
                                alert("Rejected: " + error); // error - аргумент reject
                            }
                        );


                }
            

                return f(getRelAU).then();


            },
```

Comment: `ret` не нужен, возвращать надо сам  promise и ждать пока он выполнится с then или await. Примеры есть уже в этом коде

Comment: @Grundy А можно ещё поподробнее, я немного чайник в js. Я добавил новую версию, код работает, но что-то не то возвращает, не bool значение.